# How to count the number of occurrences in a column based on values in another column in SQL?

Tags: sql, multiple-columns

Suppose we have a table like this:

```
tweet_id     tweet
1            The election was bad. Boycott the election.
2            That was great.
3            What a great election!
```

Now, I'm trying to write some SQL code which will count the number of `tweet_ids` where the corresponding `tweet` contained the word `'election'`.

I.e. both `tweet_id` 1 and 3 contained the word `'election'` at least once. Hence, I want to return the value 2 (two `tweet_ids`).

Any ideas how to do this? I tried the following, but it didn't work:

```
SELECT tweet, COUNT(*) tweet_id FROM table WHERE tweet = "election"
```

Answer (score 0):

You want `like`:

```
select count(*)
from t
where tweet like '%election%'
```

Note:  It is inappropriate to have `tweet` in the `select` because it is not aggregated.  If you want samples, use `max()` or `min()`.

Comment: Thank you. And just to clarify, this won't double count the number of tweets that contain the word 'election' will it? For instance, the first tweet contained 'election' twice, but I don't want this to count as 2. @Gordan Linoff

Comment: It only selects records where the word election is there and counts no of records. It doesn't count no of occurrences  of election

Comment: @HelpMe . . . No.  It is a actually more complicated to count the number of words in a string.

Answer (score 0):

You can use like to check if it contains "election" keyword and then count the ids

```
SELECT COUNT(tweet_id) 
FROM table 
WHERE LOWER(tweet) LIKE "%election%"
```